# Importing CSS files into React components

Tags: css, reactjs, css-loader

I'm designing a React component to publish to NPM, and I'm unable to load a css file into my component. I get the error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './styles.css'.

I'm using relative pathing, and I'm sure the path is correct.

I've tried installing css-loader, styles-loader, and sass-loader, with no luck. I'm not using webpack either.

The line I'm using to import the CSS file in my component is

```
import './styles.css';
```

I'd like to know how one can import CSS files into React components?

Comment: With Webpack, it's simply a matter of loading `css-loader` or `styles-loader` as a module

Comment: You mentioned "I'm not using webpack either.". `css-loader` and `style-loader` won't work without Webpack. If you don't want to bring in Webpack for your module, you will need to use inline styles or a css-in-js library like `styled-components` instead.

Comment: I did `npm install --save webpack` and it still can't resolve the css file.

Comment: Did you create a `webpack.config.js` file and set up `css-loader` and `style-loader` there?